# Property 'username' does not exist on type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, rxjs

```js
export let microEventBus: MicroEventBus = (window as any).microEventBus;
export interface IAppState {
  showDetails: boolean;
  product: IProduct | null;
  collectionInstance: Collection;
  username: string;
}

//const collectionInstance = new Collection();
class App extends React.Component<IAppProps, IAppState> {
  constructor(props: IAppProps) {
    super(props);
    this.showDetailView = this.showDetailView.bind(this);
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      showDetails: false,
      product: null,
      collectionInstance: new Collection(),
      username: '',
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.processUserLoginEvent = this.processUserLoginEvent.bind(this);
    microEventBus.on('user-logged-in').subscribe(this.processUserLoginEvent);
    ajax.getJSON('http://128.0.0.1:3000/products').subscribe((data) => {
      let collection = new Collection();
      collection.items = data as IProduct[];
      this.setState({
        showDetails: false,
        product: null,
        collectionInstance: collection,
      });
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.collectionInstance.items.length < 1 ? (
          <div className='App-header'>
            <CircularProgress />
          </div>
        ) : (
          ''
        )}
        <CollectionView
          {...this.state.collectionInstance}
          handlerItemClicked={this.showDetailView}></CollectionView>
        <DetailView
          open={this.state.showDetails}
          product={this.state.product}
          handleClose={this.handleClose}
**problem**-->username={this.state.username}></DetailView>
```

I have problem with a code. I got a type error for username property. I try to change type of string to a type of any but that did't solved my problem. Any sugestions ?

ERROR:

> Type '{ open: boolean; product: IProduct | null; handleClose: () =>
> void; username: string; }' is not assignable to type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes &
> Readonly & Readonly<...>'.   Property 'username' does
> not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
> IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly &
> Readonly<...>'.ts(2322)

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it seems that the `DetailView` component does not support a `username` prop. That is to say, the error you see with the following code:

```js
      <DetailView
          open={this.state.showDetails}
          product={this.state.product}
          handleClose={this.handleClose}
          username={this.state.username}></DetailView>
```

is not because `username` is absent on state, but because the `DetailView` component expects different props.

Comment: U are right. I forgot to edit my interface in DetailView file and add a username property. I need to read a code first and then ask a dummy questions. Tnx again.